# How to access custom view inflated in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I need to access the view that has been inflated in a `DialogFragment`. `inflater` and `container` appear to be unresolved but yet when I add these to the parentheses of `onCreateDialog`, the `overrides nothing` error is returned. What is the correct solution in this case?

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_sample, container, false)

        lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
        lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager

        builder.setIconAttribute(R.attr.imgNight)
        builder.setTitle("My Program")
        builder.setView(rootView)
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }

        tabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
        viewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager)

        val adapter = CustomAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment("Boy", CustomFragment.createInstance("Oscar"))
        adapter.addFragment("Girl", CustomFragment.createInstance("Stacy"))
        adapter.addFragment("Robot", CustomFragment.createInstance("Aeon"))
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        return builder.create()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `container` pass null since there isn't a parent view. As for the `inflater` use `LayoutInflater.from(requireContext)`.

You can then use the view in the dialog builder.

Comment: So `LayoutInflater.from(requireContext)` replaces `inflater`? `Null` should not be used as the view root.

Comment: Yes like so `val rootView = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_sample, null, false)`

Comment: `null` returns a warning: ‘Avoid passing `null` as the view root’

Comment: Yes this is just a warning but it works and doesn't error out. There are a few ways around but they are error prone and depend on proper timing which fails across the large range of android devices.

Comment: There is another option which is to use `onCreateView` and don't use `AlertDialog` or `onCreateDialog`. The drawback is you have to handle all view components including the title and the buttons, but you won't have any warnings.

Comment: Running the code causes the app to crash. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749729/dialogfragment-not-appearing)

Comment: Please post the stacktrace?